# Elixir - ** (Jason.DecodeError) unexpected end of input at position 0

Tags: json, elixir, runtime-error

After successfully polling an API nine times, this error sprang up. What is it attempting to communicate? Why does it come up after so many good polls? What concrete steps should I take to resolve this?

Thanks for addressing these questions! :)

Comment: You should edit your question and give some code in there. What is the input?

Comment: My guess would be that on the ninth time you got a response body that's not JSON, perhaps a 500 or somesuch, so the parser couldn't parse it.

Comment: Thanks @PawełObrok for disambiguating  this for me!

Answer (score 0):

The argument you are passing to `Jason.decode` is not valid JSON. In this case it's most likely the response body you got back from the API endpoint. It's likely a string of plain text or HTML, such as:

```
Internal Server Error
```

You will need to share your code in order for someone to provide a version of the code that can handle all of the responses you are getting from the API.